# Oracle IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: oracle, macos

I am getting this error, but over mac An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

> IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
>
> Vendor code 17002

I am not able to know where to get into services from mac , like windows. What solution?I am using version 19.0.1 latest

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: all i want is local database. nothing on a server.

Comment: its strange, all i do search its solutions over windows. no mac.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Check your IP by Apple -> System Preferences -> Network -> Click on a Network Service (Wifi connection or Ethernet connection) .

Step 2: Go to Applications -> Network Utility -> Port scan -> Copy your IP address there and Scan for available TCP ports.

Step 3: enter a open TCP port as the port in your oracle connection.